# How to align arrows in between shapes in a straight line in html/css?

Tags: html, css

I have a screenshot as shown below which I am trying to replicate in html/css:

[image]

At this moment, I am able to get everything in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jeb9u44s/5/embedded/result/) with green and orange arrows not properly aligned.

The CSS codes which I have used in order align arrows and desktop in a straight line are:

```
.tvs
{
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
padding: 1rem;    
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the fiddle so that I am able to align green and orange arrows in a straight line in between the desktops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap them in one div element and use `text-align: center` on that div.

```css
.tvs {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.arrows-element {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="tvs">

  <div class="arrows">
    <img src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/End-Arrows-left.png" alt="" width="49" height="62" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-8105" />
  </div>
  <div class="tv">
    <img src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Tv-Screen-2.png" alt="" width="177" height="129" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-8081" />
  </div>

  <div class="arrows-element">
    <div class="green-arrow">
      <img src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/green-arrow.png" alt="" width="49" height="24" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-8109">
    </div>

    <div class="orange-arrow">
      <img src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/orange-arrow-v1.png" alt="" width="126" height="24" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-8114" />
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="tv">
    <img src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Tv-Screen-2.png" alt="" width="177" height="129" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-8081" />
  </div>

  <div class="arrows-element">
    <div class="green-arrow">
      <img src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/green-arrow.png" alt="" width="49" height="24" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-8109">
    </div>

    <div class="orange-arrow">
      <img src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/orange-arrow-v1.png" alt="" width="126" height="24" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-8114" />
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="tv">
    <img src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Tv-Screen-2.png" alt="" width="177" height="129" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-8081" />
  </div>

  <div class="arrows-element">
    <div class="green-arrow">
      <img src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/green-arrow.png" alt="" width="49" height="24" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-8109">
    </div>

    <div class="orange-arrow">
      <img src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/orange-arrow-v1.png" alt="" width="126" height="24" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-8114" />
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="tv">
    <img src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Tv-Screen-2.png" alt="" width="177" height="129" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-8081" />
  </div>

  <div class="arrows">
    <img src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/End-Arrows-right.png" alt="" width="49" height="62" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-8105" />
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @Nenand Vracar I have accepted your answer. It looks good. I have one more quick question. In order to make it look exactly as the screenshot, I have used margin between arrows and made some changes in the class. Let me know if this is right.  Here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jeb9u44s/20/embedded/result/)